# Memory warnings when loading UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, didreceivememorywarning

I'm executing a request using `ASIHTTPRequest`. I'm then loading into a `UIWebView` the data I get in the response. Sometimes, when the amount of data is long, I get memory warnings followed by the app being killed, although I'm setting to nil the properties I don't need in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

I checked in Instruments that I don't have any memory leak.

I could find lots of posts about this issue, but I didn't find an answer. Is there a way to render the `UIWebView` partially, like the Mail app does when we're seeing a long email and scrolling fast, showing a checkerboard background while loading?

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving you data to a file first, then pointing the UIWebView at it for loading.  ASIHTTPRequest can also save a response directly to a file as it streams in.

How big is your data?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I realised the problem is that since I have a lot of text to show, the height of the UIWebView is too high - over 26000. I'll have to tile the UIWebView somehow...